# Call function after HTML is loaded AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Guys I have the following directive :

```
angular.module('blah').directive('someDirective', function () {
   return {
        scope: {
            arrayParam1: '=arrayParam1',
            arrayParam2: '=arrayParam2'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/my/path/to/someDirective.tpl.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { 
            //Some logic
            scope.someEvent = function(){
              //some logic
            }
            scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
                debugger;
                scope.someEvent();
            });
        }
   };
});
```

Now in the HTML I have a ng-repeat over one of the arrays(*arrayParam1* for example) and I am display some stuff. Now my goal as you can assume is to trigger the *scope.someEvent* after the HTML is completely loaded (finished with the iterations of ng-repeat).

Well when I use the **$on** it does not even stop on the debugger. If I change it to **$watch** it does stop after all the code is finished in the JS but the HTML is still not rendered and it triggers the even I want before the view is done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use timeout instead of viewContentLoaded

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TheMechanic Well yes I know about timeout but I wanted it to do it as clear as I can. @ Iso The goal is far more complecated then the example I wrote. I am creating accordian with ng-repeat and after it is done in the HTML I want dynamiclly to add elements to every pane (from js).

Comment: @lazarov Why don’t you add elements inside `ng-repeat` then?

Comment: @lazarov for dom manipulation in angular it's better you would play with array instead of dom elements

Comment: @Iso It is too complecated to do all of the logic only by html. Like I said it is far more bigger problem from the one I posted for example.

Answer (score 1):

use $timeout.

```
$timeout(function () {
   scope.someEvent();         
});
```

this will help.

or if you don't want to use **$timeout** what you have to do is make another directive parent to this directive and execute or trigger the function in parents link phase

Comment: Its bad practice to use `timeout`.

Comment: yes it is bad. But then what he have to do is make another directive parent to this directive and execute or trigger the function in parents link phase.