# Create html elements in ngRepeat depending on object properties

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects that have two fileds for example :

```
var array = [{type:"range", group:"group1"}, {type:"boolean", group:"group1"}, 
 {type:"input", group:"group3"}... ]
```

Now in HTML by iterating through the array I want to create a div for every different GROUP and put the all elements with that group inside. But by putting I mean creating Inputs or Radiobuttons or Dropdowns depending on the TYPE of the element.

Now I have done this using AngularJS and mostly JS by appending objects to existing ones and so on. But I want to reduce as much as possible the usage of js because I am having issue with calling a function after the HTML is loaded ([Call function after HTML is loaded AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715922/call-function-after-html-is-loaded-angularjs)).

So I will be thankfull if someone give me an advice how this should look like mostly in html. I imagine something like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="object in array track by $index">
  //if object.group div exists add to existing one (check maybe with js function ?)
     // if object.type is ... add ... 
     // else if objec.type is ... add ...
     ...
  //else object.group not exists create div with id object.group for example
     // if object.type is ... add ...
     // else if object.type is ... add ...
     ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for your case:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in array | groupBy: 'group'">
  Group: {{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="object in value">
      <div ng-switch on="object.type">
        <div ng-switch-when="range">Range block</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="boolean">Boolean block</div>
        <div ng-switch-when="input">Input block</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

First looping groups elements, second will work with an elements in a group

Comment: Thanks looks legit.